# GZip doesn't work in Webpack 2.5.1

Tags: angular, webpack, compression, gzip, jscompress

I use webpack 2.5.1 and I want to reduce my files size, because my hardware doesn't support files above 7,8 hundred kilobytes. I reduce my main-client.js to 2.63 mb with production mode and uglify, but I want to use gzip and I don't know how...

[image]

If I remove CompressionPlugin code I still have 2.63 mb... it doesn't work now... What do I wrong...?

[image]

I found this link, but I don't know where to add code from 2.2 -> 4.

[Two Quick Ways To Reduce React App’s Size In Production](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a)

I accept another methods too, for compressing that js file/s :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's a server level configuration AFAIK.

Have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/09/05/iis-dynamic-compression-and-new-dynamic-compression-features-in-iis-10/

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

or

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/

Depending on the server you are using. In NodeJS if you're using express there's https://github.com/expressjs/compression, and in ASP.NET CORE MVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 1):

Gziping files is a server feature, you can just enable them in the server that is serving the static files.

I would suggest you to update to webpack 4 and apply code splitting to your code, it will decrease its size.